# Why duty cycle can be greater than 50 in a forward converter with active clamp?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, forward

In a forward converter, the theoretical limit of the duty cycle is 0.5. This is necessary in order to have time to discharge the magnetizing inductance of the transformation. However, the duty cycle may be higher in an active clamp type forward converter. For example in [MAX17599](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX17598-MAX17599.pdf).

Why is this possible?

Comment: What voltage does an active clamp allow the flux to be reset at? Total Vs must be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is **de-magnetisation**. The basic concept about de-magnetisation is "volt-seconds balance". I'm not going to dive into details about the topic but all I can say in simpler terms is that the volt-seconds (or flux density swing, \$\Delta B\$) in one direction should be equal to the one in the opposite direction in order to achieve de-magnetisation of the magnetic core *(Or in other words, net volt-seconds product over a period should be zero)*. Or else the core will saturate after some time.

For example, if the flux density swing is 80 mT when the switch is on and -70 mT when the switch is off then, this 10 mT difference will eventually cause the peak flux density to reach the saturation point. Imagine the B-H (hysteresis) curve and the movements along the curve, you'll understand better:

[image]

<sup>[Image Source](https://www.themegaguide.com/2020/05/%20Hysteresis-Loop.html)</sup>

Therefore, your following statement

> In a forward converter, the theoretical limit of the duty cycle is 0.5.

is **not** exactly correct. Assuming a forward converter with reset winding (a.k.a. traditional forward converter) is what you meant, having the reset winding **same number of turns** as the primary power winding's will **limit** the duty cycle to 0.5 (or 50%), yes. But you can go beyond 50% duty cycle by increasing the reset winding's number of turns *(remember volt-seconds again - higher voltage on the reset winding brings lower off-time for the same volt-seconds, therefore the on-time and thus the duty cycle can be effectively increased)* but this will increase the voltage stress on the main power switch i.e. goes even higher than twice the bus (input) voltage. Keeping the voltage stress at a maximum of twice the bus voltage is the common practice (because of the high-voltage MOSFET availability, possibly) and this is where that so-called limit of 50% for duty-cycle comes from.

For [two-switch forward converter](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91616/twoswitch.pdf) (a.k.a. double-ended forward converter), however, the duty-cycle limit **is** 50% (neglecting the diode drops) because there's no reset winding, so when the switch is off the clamping is done towards the bus lines. Therefore the max duty-cycle can't be higher than 50%, naturally.

---

For active clamp forward, things are a bit different.

When the switch is on, the voltage across the primary (magnetisation) winding is the bus voltage, V<sub>B</sub>. When the switch is off the voltage across the primary is V<sub>CL</sub> - V<sub>B</sub>, where V<sub>CL</sub> is the clamping capacitor voltage. For volt-seconds balance we can write

$$
\mathrm{V_B \ T_{ON} = (V_{CL}-V_B) \ T_{OFF} \\
\Rightarrow V_B \ D \ T_S = (V_{CL}-V_B) \ (1-D) \ T_S}
$$

where D is the duty cycle, T<sub>S</sub> is the switching period, and T<sub>ON</sub> and T<sub>OFF</sub> are on and off durations, respectively. Now from the equation above we can write the clamping capacitor voltage:

$$
\mathrm{V_{CL}=\frac{V_B}{1-D}}
$$

This voltage is also equal to the voltage stress of the main power switch.

> Why is this possible?

Now, as you can see from the equation above, we have a so-called adjustable (not exactly adjustable but let's assume so for the sake of simplicity) clamping voltage, and this adjustment is done by the duty-cycle. Now if the duty-cycle is kept below 50% then the voltage stress of the main power switch can be reduced to somewhere between V<sub>B</sub> and 2V<sub>B</sub>, instead of 2V<sub>B</sub> regardless of the duty cycle as in traditional forward converter.

For low input voltage applications (e.g. 48 V nominal, 56 V max) the duty-cycle can be pushed beyond 50%, allowing the voltage across the primary winding to be higher. This will also reduce the primary current because the primary-to-secondary turns ratio can be higher.